# Exporting discussion board with all the replies

Tags: 2010, excel, discussion-board

Is there any way to export a discussion board to Excel *with all the replies*?

I've tried clicking on *Export to Excel* from the ribbon, but what I get isn't what I want as this does not give me the replies. I've read somewhere about opening the discussion board in Access and exporting to Excel from there, but we don't have the option of using Access.

Answer (score 1):

Archiving the Discussion Board to include replies:

1. Go to Q&A Board and select specific Q&A Board you want to archive
2. Select “List” under List Tools and Select “Modify View”
3. Scroll to second to last item “Folders”
4. Change Folders or Flat: to Show all items without folders
5. Change Show this view: to In all folders.

**This will allow you to export the Discussion Board with Replies**

6. Click on “List” in the List Tools menu and select “Export to Excel”.
7. Click OK to the dialog box (if it pops ups)
8. Click Open to the dialog box about open or save
9. Next Microsoft Excel will open - Click Enable.
10. If this is the first Discussion Board you are archiving, the export process will begin.  If you have already exported one of the discussion boards to Excel, you will see an Import Data dialog box.
11. Change the radio button to “New worksheet” and click OK.  This will create an additional tab in Excel document you have created.
12. The process of exporting the discussion board begins and can take up to 2-3 minutes.
13. When the discussion board is imported into the Excel worksheet, it is very spread out.  Click on the worksheet and press Ctrl-A on your keyboard to select all of the content on that sheet.
14. Right click on the worksheet and click on Format Cells
15. In the Format Cells dialog box, click on the Alignment Tab.
16. Click on the Wrap text box two times.  After the first click, you will see a check mark and after the second click, the box should be blank.  When it looks like the screenshot below, click OK.
17. Your information collapses into a smaller area.  Now, go to the bottom of the Excel spreadsheet where the tabs are shown.  Each new tab is named with “Sheet #.”  For ease of locating information, rename the tab to the particular discussion board.  To rename the tab, right click on the tab and click on Rename.
18. Then you can type the new name into the tab   When you are done, click off of the tab.

*Save the Excel document.

IMPORTANT:

Once the Q&A Boards have been exported, you might want to change the view back: 
o   Change Folders or Flat: to Show items inside folders
o   Change Show this view: to In the top-level folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this captures all replies, but it doesn't cut off the "body" of the discussion board like all other methods do.

1. Connect the Discussion Board to Outlook.
2. Create a new folder in your Outlook inbox.
3. Find the SharePoint list in Outlook and copy all of the items from there to the new folder you created.
4. Export the new folder to a Tab Separated Values (Windows) file. <-- Important
5. Open the exported file with notepad.
6. Copy all and Paste into Excel.